# Console doesn't output unicode characters

Tags: c, unicode, console

I'm currently making a console Tetris game for learning the basics of C.
However, I can't get any Unicode characters to be printed on the console.
People just use `printf("■□□□■■■□□■■□□■■");` but this does not work for me.
Also, I can't manually type Unicode characters to the console either.

Comment: This is highly dependent on your individual system configuration. You will have to make sure, that your console, whatever it is (tty, xterm, etc.), really supports unicode and is in the correct mode. Furthermore the font used must support the unicode characters you want to print. There are probably even more points to consider...

Comment: You need to give more details. Specifically, what machine and operating system are you running? Also, most likely you are running in a console window, but you don't say that either. In any case, it is not uncommon for said console windows to lack Unicode support. In that case this is a system support question rather than a programming question.

Comment: If it's just for leaning the basics of C, can't you just use ASCII characters for the Tetris blocks? You could use different characters to represent different shades/colors for the tetrominoes.

Comment: Your console will have to be configured to expect/use Unicode (probably UTF-8) as the code set.  How you do that configuration depends on the o/s you're running on, and the console (terminal) program you're using.  Please identify the platform (primarily Linux vs Windows vs macOS) and version, and on the Unix-like systems, which terminal program you're using.

Comment: I"m using windows and cmd for this project.

Answer (score 0):

To write Unicode directly to the console you should use wide character APIs and enable stdout to use UTF-16.  Your source file should be saved in `UTF-8 with BOM` (at least with the Microsoft compilers):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ∞φε∩≡±\n");
    wprintf(L"\u0518\n"); // CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YAE U+0518
}
```

Output:

```
░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀αßΓπΣσµτΦΘΩδ∞φε∩≡±
Ԙ
```

Your output will vary depending on your font support for the characters printed.  The first line of characters are commonly supported on US Windows 10.  The second line is a Unicode character outside the normal US code pages but supported by the Consolas font.  It is specified using its Unicode code point via an escape code, but could be typed directly in the source via a tool like Windows Character Map or installing an appropriate Input Method Editor(IME).